# remove input with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have a problem at javascript code level, in fact I want when I choose option = apartment it shows me 3 input text and if I click after option = home it removes the 3 input text.
But my code does not remove the 3 input if I chose house.

```js
document.getElementById('contrat').onchange = function() {
  if (this.value == 'appartement') {
    console.log('appartement');
    var new_input1 = document.createElement('input');
    var new_input2 = document.createElement('input');
    var new_input3 = document.createElement('input');

    new_input1.type = "text";
    new_input1.id = 'ascenseur';
    new_input1.name = 'ascenceur';
    new_input1.placeholder = 'oui/non';
    new_input1.setAttribute("class", "form-control");

    new_input2.type = "text";
    new_input2.id = 'code';
    new_input2.name = 'code';
    new_input2.placeholder = 'code/interphone';
    new_input2.setAttribute("class", "form-control");

    new_input3.type = "text";
    new_input3.id = 'porte';
    new_input3.name = 'porte';
    new_input3.placeholder = 'la porte';
    new_input3.setAttribute("class", "form-control");

    document.getElementById('champ2').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('champ3').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('champ4').innerHTML = "";

    document.getElementById('champ2').appendChild(new_input1);
    document.getElementById('champ3').appendChild(new_input2);
    document.getElementById('champ4').appendChild(new_input3);
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Logement* </label>
  <select id="contrat" class=form-control name="logement">
    <option>--------</option>
    <option value="appartement">Appartement</option>
    <option value="maison">Maison</option>
    <option value="autre">Autre</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div id="champ2"></div>
  <div id="champ3"></div>
  <div id="champ4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code does something only when the selected value is "appartement".

Comment: You might find it easier to include all inputs in the HTML then `.show()` / `.hide()` them when you change the `select`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to check if its `maison`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sfr3wb2p/1/

```
  if (this.value == 'maison') {
    document.getElementById('champ2').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('champ3').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('champ4').innerHTML = "";  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an extra if `$(this).val() === 'maison'` to empty when this option is selected. Also changed your plain Javascript code to jQuery to show you how this is done since you tagged your question with jQuery.

As said in the comments, you might want to consider to just hide and show the elements. This way the value of the input is not lost when changing the select.

```js
$('#contrat').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() === 'appartement') {
    console.log('appartement');
    var $new_input1 = $('<input>');
    var $new_input2 = $('<input>');
    var $new_input3 = $('<input>');

    $new_input1.attr('type', 'text')
      .attr('type', 'ascenseur')
      .attr('name', 'ascenceur')
      .attr('placeholder', 'oui/non')
      .attr("class", "form-control");

    $new_input2.attr('type', 'text')
      .attr('type', 'code')
      .attr('name', 'code')
      .attr('placeholder', 'code/interphone')
      .attr("class", "form-control");

    $new_input3.attr('type', 'text')
      .attr('type', 'porte')
      .attr('name', 'porte')
      .attr('placeholder', 'la porte')
      .attr("class", "form-control");

    $('#champ2').empty();
    $('#champ3').empty();
    $('#champ4').empty();

    $('#champ2').append($new_input1);
    $('#champ3').append($new_input2);
    $('#champ4').append($new_input3);
  }
  else if($(this).val() === 'maison') {
    console.log('maison');
    $('#champ2').empty();
    $('#champ3').empty();
    $('#champ4').empty();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Logement* </label>
  <select id="contrat" class=form-control name="logement">
    <option>--------</option>
    <option value="appartement">Appartement</option>
    <option value="maison">Maison</option>
    <option value="autre">Autre</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div id="champ2"></div>
  <div id="champ3"></div>
  <div id="champ4"></div>
</div>
```